# move files from multiple folder to one destination folder

Tags: unix

Dear Unix users I have for example 6 folders and in each folder I have a file called file.txt. The name of the file is exactly the same in all the folders I have. I would like to move all the files called file.txt from each of the 6 folders into a general folder that will contain all the files because I would like to concatenate the files finally. How this can be done?

Input:
folder1: file.txt,   folder2: file.txt,   folder3: file.txt

Output:
final_folder: file.txt, file.txt, file.txt

Thanks

Eleonora

Comment: I think that is not possible. You have in your target folder files with the same name, they will be overwritten. You could use the unix tool `find`, to find all files with the name `file.txt` and move them with `mv` to your target folder. But you have to rename the files. For example to file1.txt, file2.txt…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple files with the same name within the same directory. If you're planning to eventually concatenate all the files, while not just do it all at once?

For example, the following command will concatenate all `file.txt` files within directories with names that start with `folder` and write the output to `new_file.txt`:

```
cat folder*/file.txt > new_file.txt
```

If you want to include files within multi-level subdirectories, you can consider using [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find). 
The following will recursively search for `file.txt` within the current directory (and all subdirectories) and concatenate their contents into `new_file.txt`.

```
find . -name file.txt -exec cat {} \; > new_file.txt
```

Comment: Hi Shawn! Exactly! I would like to concatenate them all together. I know that no files with the same name can stay in the same folder but they are outputs of an algorithm that runs in each folder independently. I tried the code you suggested me but it doesn't work. It copies only the content of a file.txt in the final new_file.txt.

Comment: That's just an example; you'll need to modify it to suit your file structure. If you post a more specific example, we might be able to help.

Comment: yes Shawn, the problem I'm adressing is explained exactly above in my posted question. I tried to write a loop as follow: for i in folder*; do cat file.txt > new_file.txt $i; done. It doesn't work too..

Comment: You loop should look like this: `for i in folder*; do cat $i/file.txt >> new_file.txt; done`. However, there's no reason why the examples I've provided shouldn't work as well.

Comment: Hi Shawn! Now fortunately it works fine. I just want you to ask the last fast question. Each file I want to concatenate contains 17 rows at the beginning I would like to remove before concatenate because they contain the parameters I set before running the software. Is there a parameter (like head -n) able to do this for me inside cat? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `tail -n+18` instead of `cat` and you should get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

they can't all have the same name in one directory

i would do a find and then a cat into a file

```
 cat `find .name 'file' -print` path/newFile
```

Answer (score 1):

This takes care of colliding duplicate names by renaming to a name with the inodenumber prepended. The function is not strictly needed.

This method will probably fail for filenames with spaces or tabs, or worse in them. (but people who put spaces and tabs into names deserve to lose...)

```
#!/bin/sh

DIRS="dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4"
TARGET=$HOME/txt

move_one()
{
  p=$1         # Full pathname
  t=$2         # Target directory
  i=$3         # Inode number from sourcefile
  d=`dirname $p`
  b=`basename $p`
  #echo "p=$p"
  #echo "d=$d" # the path-prefix from the source file
  #echo "b=$b" # The name part of the source file
  #echo "t=$t"
  #echo "i=$i"
# After checking, remove the echo below for more fun
  echo mv -i $p $t/$i$b
}
                                        # inodenumber+name
find $DIRS -name \*txt -type f -ls | awk '{print $1," ",$11}' | (
        while read i p; do
        # echo "i=$i"
        # echo "p=$p"
        move_one $p $TARGET $i
        done
        )
#eof
```